# Is there a fast way of accessing line in AWS S3 file?

Tags: amazon-s3, line, boto

I have a collection of JSON messages in a file stored on S3 (one message per line). Each message has a unique key as part of the message. I also have a simple DynamoDB table where this key is used as the primary key. The table contains the name of the S3 file where the corresponding JSON message is located.

My goal is to extract a JSON message from the file given the key. Of course, the worst case scenario is when the message is the very last line in the file.

What is the fastest way of extracting the message from the file using the `boto` library? In particular, is it possible to somehow read the file line by line directly? Of course, I can read the entire contents to a local file using `boto.s3.key.get_file()` then open the file and read it line by line and check for the id to match. But is there a more efficient way?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 cannot do this. That said, you have some other options:

1. Store the record's length and position (byte offset) instead of the line number in DynamoDB. This would allow you to retrieve just that record using [the `Range:` header](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/boto-users/ofK9XERJeAc/hwupkxvxI1sJ).
2. Use caching layer to store `{ S3 object key, line number } => { position, length }` tuples. When you want to look up a record by `{ S3 object key, line number }`, reference the cache. If you don't already have this data, you have to fetch the whole file like you do now -- but having fetched the file, you can calculate offsets for every line within it, and save yourself work down the line.
3. Store the JSON record in DynamoDB directly. This may or may not be practical, given the 64 KB item limit.
4. Store each JSON record in S3 separately. You could then eliminate the DynamoDB key lookup, and go straight to S3 for a given record.

Which is most appropriate for you depends on your application architecture, the way in which this data is accessed, concurrency issues (probably not significant given your current solution), and your sensitivities for latency and cost.

Comment: Thanks. I am fairly new to AWS: can you tell me what 'caching layer' is? Is this part of S3? or DynamoDB?

Comment: Well, AWS is happy to sell you [ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/), but I'm not specifically referring to that. A lot of applications have some sort of caching mechanism readily accessible -- for example, [Django's cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-low-level-cache-api) -- but you could take that option with something as simple as a Python dictionary that you throw away when you're done processing. Option 2 is a way to cut down on work without changing what data you need to store.

Comment: See also [Cache (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) for a general overview on caching.

Comment: I just tried the range approach on a Ubuntu EC2 instance. Twice in a row, when I entered the command `fst = key.get_contents_as_string(headers={'Range' : 'bytes=0:1537'})` python got killed. Do you know why that might have happened?

Comment: Apparently this was caused by the wrong format of `bytes=0:1537`. Supposed to be `bytes=0-1537`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the built-in readline with streams:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {Bucket: 'yourbucket', Key: 'somefile.txt'};
const readStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: readStream,
});
lineReader.on('line', (line) => console.log(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 SELECT to accomplish this.  Also works on parquet files.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html